# How do I iterate through a dictionary's keys and execute a method for each key in the dictionary using Linq?

Tags: .net, linq

How I could fix this LINQ extension? (in C# or VB no matter):

```
States.Select(Function(item) myMethod(item.Key, item.Value))
```

`States` object is a Dictionary, and what I'm trying to reproduce using LINQ is the same as this:

```
For each item in states
    myMethod(item.Key, item.Value)
Next item
```

I know that I'm missing something because the Select extension in that way is not the solution... but, I don't know.

Comment: Keep in mind that titles need to be searchable and describe the problem you have, not the action you want us to take.  I've edited your title to show what I mean when I say that. Feel free to improve upon it if it's not exactly what you mean. The idea is that no one will ever search for, "Fix this linq method."

Comment: @George Stocker yes thankyo for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean ForEach extension, you may use it like this

```
States.ToList().ForEach(Function(item) myMethod(item.Key, item.Value))
```

Comment: Thankyou but the code is correct?, my dictionary has not that foreach method

Answer (score 1):

From your example there is no no way to "reproduce" this in linq.  The function does not return a value.  If  myMethod() returned something you could create a list of all the results like this (C#)

```
var resultlist = States.Select(item => myMethod(item.Key,item.Value));
```

But there is no reason to use linq if the method does not return a value -- just use the for each like you had originally.

Comment: so there is no way to use LINQ to "process a secuence" like a FOR does? then LINQ ALWAYS expects to return a value yes or yes? is that? thankyou for your answer!

Comment: @ElektroStudios - Linqs works on Enumerations which are sort of like sequences -- they have an order and can be processed sequentially.  But from a programming point of view you can use a for each unless you plan on continuing to transform the results.

Comment: Yes you have reason that For is the best in performance than doing unnecessary conversions + LINQ, but I asked how to reproduce that For for curiosity. thankyou again

Answer (score 1):

Linq is for *querying* - it is designed to iterate over a collection and *return* a result for each item.  There are `ForEach` extension methods out there that just wrap `foreach`, but in my opinion ([and](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2009/04/08/why-i-don-t-use-the-foreach-extension-method.aspx) [others'](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mazhou/archive/2011/09/21/why-no-foreach-method-on-ienumerable-interfaces.aspx)) they are pointless because they only *change* the syntax, they do not *improve* it.

You *could* fake it out in C# by returning a dummy value:

```
States.Select(item => {myMethod(item.Key, item.Value); return 0;})
```

or in VB:

```
States.Select(Function(item) 
                myMethod(item.Key, item.Value) 
                Return 1 
              End Function)
```

but I think that just adds confusing noise - a `foreach` is definitely more appropriate.